# SASS mixin for grid layout

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Let's say that we have the following markup:

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <div>column1</div>
    <div>column2</div>
    <div>column3</div>
    <div>column4</div>
</section>
```

I need a mixin which will set equally the width of the columns and will float them to the left. A simple four column grid. Here is what I came up so far.

```
@mixin grid($columns: 2, $tag: "div") {
    #{$tag} {
        width: 100% / $columns;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
    }
    &:after {
        display: table;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
}
```

My question is: is there any better way to do this and do I miss something.

Comment: Have you investigated any existing grid systems before attempting to write your own?  Also, this is a bit off topic for SO (might be more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Actually, I have some experience with Bootstrap and Foundation, but I don't think that they follow the best approach. I mean having classes for various widths is not always helpful and it doesn't cover all the possible cases. I'll agree with you that my question is more like a code review request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [singularitygs](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity)!

With this sass extension you can write

```
div {
    @include grid-span(1,1,4,$output-style: 'float');
}
```

The parameters for `grid-span` are `(with, startpos, context, options)`. All numbers will be converted to ratio-based widths. The above example can be read as:

```
width 1 at position 1 in a grid-context of 4
=> width: 25%; margin-left: 0;
```

(`ouput-style: 'float'` is needed, because you are targeting multiple divs)

Or you can define your base grid first, and leave out the context:

```
$grids: 4;

div {
    @include grid-span(1,1,$output-style: 'float');
}
```

You can even go further and use `breakpoints` to have different grids for different window sizes:

```
$grids: 4; // base grid (mobile first)
$grids: add-grid(12 at 980px); // 12-grid for everything above 980px
$output-style: 'float'; // set the output-style globally
div {
    @include grid-span(2,1); // => 50%
    @include breakpoint(980px) {
        @include grid-span(4,1); => 33.3333%
    }
}
```

There is alot more possible with Singularity, so check out their [wiki](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki)!